# I met this error when executing a function - TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python

Can anybody help me with this? I'm a beginner in python and programming. Thanks very much.
I got this TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable when I execute this  function.

```
def goodVsEvil(good, evil):
GoodTeam = {'Hobbits':1, 'Men':2, 'Elves':3, 'Dwarves':3, 'Eagles':4, 'Wizards':10}
EvilTeam = {'Orcs':1, 'Men':2, 'Wargs':2, 'Goblins':2, 'Uruk Hai':3, 'Trolls':5, 'Wizards':10}
Gworth = 0
Eworth = 0
for k, val in GoodTeam():
    Input = raw_input ('How many of {0} : ')
    Gworth = Gworth + int(Input) * val
for k, val in EvilTeam():
    inp = raw_input ('How many of {0} : ')
    Eworth = Eworth + int(inp) * val
if Gworth > Eworth:
    return 'Battle Result: Good triumphs over Evil'
if Eworth > Gworth:
    return 'Battle Result: Evil eradicates all trace of Good'
if Eworth == Gworth:
    return 'Battle Result: No victor on this battle field'
```

Comment: Please always include at least the last paragraph of a traceback, stating at which *line* the error occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those parenthesis are unnecessary. You intend to use `.items()` which allows you to iterate on the keys and values of your dictionary:

```
for k, val in GoodTeam.items():
    # your code
```

You should replicate this change for `EvilTeam` also.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, `GoodTeam` is a dict, but you're trying to call it. I think you mean to call its `items` method:

```
for k, val in GoodTeam.items():
```

The same is true for BadTeam.

Note you have other errors; you're using the string format method but haven't given it anything to actually format.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want .